# Access Boundfield in GridView control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, boundfield

I have a GridView like the one below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdProjects" runat="server" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="proLeadName" SortExpression="proLeadName" HeaderText="???" />
```

I would like to set BoundField's HeaderText attribute value from code behind. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by the index of the `Columns` collection, like this:

```
grdProjects.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Your Text Here";
```

Note: Obviously, adjust the index value for whatever column you need it to be. Also, do this before you `DataBind()` the grid.